# I'm programming UART on STM32F103C6. I made the code below but when I try it, it's not working. Could anyone help me find my error?

Tags: c, stm32, uart, bare-metal

I'm programming UART on the STM32F103C6 using BAREMETAL in C. However, when I go to simulate it in Proteus Software it doesn't work! I made another program using HAL, with this work, but not with the code in BAREMETAL. Can anyone help me find my error?

```
#include "stm32f103x6.h"

#define USART2EN        (1U<<17)
#define GPIOAEN         (1U<<2)
#define CR1_UE          (1U<<13)
#define CR1_M           (1U<<12)
#define CR1_TE          (1U<<3)
#define CR1_RE          (1U<<2)
#define SR_TXE          (1U<<7)
#define SR_RXNE         (1U<<5)
#define SR_TC           (1U<<6)
#define BAUDRATE        115200
#define APB1_FREQ       8000000

/*Função que configura o clock*/
void SysClockConfig(void)
{
    /***********>>>> PASSO A PASSO <<<<***********
     * 1. ENABLE HSI and wait to become ready internal 8 MHz RC Oscillator
     * 2. Set the POWER ENABLE CLOCK
     * 3. Configure the PRESCALERS MCLK, PCLK1, PCLK2 (peripheral clocks)
     **********************************************/

    //1. ENABLE HSE and wait for the MSE to become ready (external crystal)
    RCC->CR |= RCC_CR_HSION; // habilita o clock externo
    while (!(RCC->CR & RCC_CR_HSIRDY)){} // quer dizer que o oscilador estar pronto

    //2. Set the POWER ENABLE CLOCK
    RCC->APB1ENR |= RCC_APB1ENR_PWREN;

    //Desabilita o PLL primeiro
    RCC->CR &=~ (1U<<24);
    while (!(RCC->CR & (1U<<25))){} // aguarda ate o PLL ser desligado

    //Configura o PLL para HSI/2 * 2 = 8Mhz (sendo o HSI = 8MHz)

    RCC->CFGR &= ~(RCC_CFGR_PLLSRC | RCC_CFGR_PLLMULL); // primeiro zera os bits
    // Deixa os bits 18 a 21  PLLMUL = 0000 = PLL input clock x 2
    RCC->CFGR &=~ (1U<<18);
    RCC->CFGR &=~ (1U<<19);
    RCC->CFGR &=~ (1U<<20);
    RCC->CFGR &=~ (1U<<21);
    // Deixa o bit 16 PLLSRC = 0 = HSI oscillator clock / 2 selected as PLL input clock
    RCC->CFGR &=~ (1U<<16);

    //Habilita o PLL
    RCC->CR |= (1U<<24);
    while (RCC->CR & (1U<<25)){} // aguarda ate o PLL estar pronto


    //3. Configurar os PRESCALERS AHB, APB1 e APB2 (peripheral clocks)
    //AHB PR
    RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_HPRE_DIV1; // divide por 1
    //APB1 PR
    RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_PPRE1_DIV1;// divide por 1
    //APB2 PR
    RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_PPRE2_DIV1;// divide por 1


    // Seleciona o clock do sistema para PLL
    RCC->CFGR &=~ RCC_CFGR_SW;
    RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_SW_PLL;

    while ((RCC->CFGR & RCC_CFGR_SWS) != RCC_CFGR_SWS_PLL); // Espera ate que o PLL seja selecionado como clock

}
```

Next I made the UART settings

```
void uart2_tx_init(void)
{
    /*** CONFIGURA O GPIOA QUE É ONDE ESTA CONECTADO O TX DO UART2 ***/

    /* 1- Habilitar o sinal de clock ao GPIO A*/
    RCC->APB2ENR |= GPIOAEN;

    /*Configurar o PA2 (TX) e PA3 (RX)*/
    //PA2
    GPIOA->CRL &=~(GPIO_CRL_CNF2 | GPIO_CRL_MODE2 | GPIO_CRL_CNF3 | GPIO_CRL_MODE3);
    GPIOA->CRL &=~(1U<<8);//seta bit 8 para 0
    GPIOA->CRL |= (1U<<9);//seta bit 9 para 1
    GPIOA->CRL &=~ (1U<<10);//seta bit 10 para 0
    GPIOA->CRL |= (1U<<11);//seta bit 11 para 1

    //PA3
    GPIOA->CRL &=~(1U<<12);//seta bit 12 para 0
    GPIOA->CRL |= (1U<<13);//seta bit 13 para 1
    GPIOA->CRL &=~ (1U<<14);//seta bit 14 para 0
    GPIOA->CRL |= (1U<<15);//seta bit 15 para 1


    /*** CONFIGURA O PERIFERICO UART ***/

    /* 1- Habilitar o sinal de clock ao periferico UART2*/
    RCC->APB1ENR |= USART2EN;

    /*Habilitar o USART no registrador de controle*/
    USART2->CR1 |= CR1_UE;

    /*Seleciona para 1 Start bit, 8 Data bits, n Stop bit */
    USART2->CR1 &=~ CR1_M;

    /*Numero de Stop bits em 1*/
    USART2->CR2 &=~ (1U<<12);
    USART2->CR2 &=~ (1U<<13);

    /*Configura o Baud Rate com fclk de 8Mhz e bd 1500*/
    USART2->BRR = (5U<<0) | (4U<<4);//(unsigned)(APB1_FREQ/BAUDRATE);

    /*Habilita a transferencia (Tx) ->  to send an idle frame as first transmission.*/
    USART2->CR1 |= CR1_TE;

    /*Habilida o recebimento*/
    USART2->CR1 |= CR1_RE;

}
```

In the and i made the functions that can transmit and receive

```
void UART2_SendChar(int ch)
{
    while (!(USART2->SR & SR_TXE)){}

    USART2->DR = (ch & 0xFF);

}



char UART2_ReceiveChar(void)
{
    while (!(USART2->SR & SR_RXNE)); // Espera até receber um caractere

    return USART2->DR; // Retorna o caractere recebido
}


int main (void)
{
    SysClockConfig();
    uart2_tx_init();

    while(1)
    {
        UART2_SendChar('m');
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't work"? Is no data getting sent, are you receiving gibberish, what? Also for the real application, have you looked at the actual signals using your oscilloscope?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]" and other pages of the [help]. Then come back and [edit] your question to clarify, as Lundin suggests.

Comment: Suggested debug: Are you stuck in a loop?  Add something to loops like `while (!(USART2->SR & SR_TXE)){}`, `while (!(USART2->SR & SR_RXNE));`, ... to stop and complain if they iterate too many times.

Comment: You probably need a (small) delay between enabling a peripheral's clock and accessing its registers.

Comment: You did not read the Reference manual properly.

Comment: The char 'm' in the while loop inside the main i just send to test the program. But when i test this code in the Proteus the virtual terminal doesn't recive the 'm' sent in the while loop. And i don't have an oscilloscope.

I will try the delay between enabling a peripheral's clock and accessing its registers. Thanks

Comment: you are doing two things here at a minimum you are messing with the clock system, first off why, if this is bare metal it comes out of reset using internal.  make the uart work with that.  if you want to mess with the clock use something like the systick timer to see that you didnt brick the thing and that the clock is doing what you want.   second is the uart, which again do that  independently of messing with the clock.  IMO start with N81 and send 0x55 as fast as you can and look on a scope to see the baud rate (or use another mcu to measure the time).

Comment: some, not all of the stm32s do need a delay between clock enable and starting to talk to the peripheral block although with these it is very strange and at the same time the C code can work or not work depending, particularly with this scary union/struct or equals, you need to look at the disassembly to see the timing even a single instruction  related to how volatile is implemented by that compiler for that code will make it work or not.

Comment: This is wrong: `while (!(RCC->CR & (1U<<25))){} // aguarda ate o PLL ser desligado` this checks RCC_CR.PLLRDY, and if it is zero, it will loop - but as in previous line you switched off PLL which was already switched off, this bit is already zero and will remain zero, so the program will keep looping at that line infinitely - can you single-step in proteus and check yourself? The second check for RCC_CR.PLLRDY after you switch PLL on is also wrong in the same way (but the bit is opposite there). I haven't looked at the rest of the program.